# Remove the populated value once the dropdown list changed

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have been working hard to populate data from the mysql using php, jquery, ajax, but the data retrieved was not remove or reload after the dropdown list changed. Is there anything to add to this code?

```
 function fetch_select(val) {
    console.log(val);
     $.ajax({
       type: 'post',
       url: 'action.php?id=select-project',
       data: {
         get_option:val
       },
       dataType: 'json',  
       success: function(data)    {    

      // success: function (response) {
        //var data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
          $.each(data, function(index, row){
              var fullname = row.fullname;      
              var number = row.number;           
          $('#display').append("<tr style=\"background-color:#ccc\"><td>id: </td><td> name: </td></tr><tr><td>"+number+"</td><td>"+fullname+"</td></tr>"); 
}); 
       }
     });
}
```

Comment: Are you getting `data` in `success`? I mean your ajax call has been succeeded? If you are getting data how it actually looks like?

Comment: add an error handler and put some log statement to check your API response

Comment: yeah everything works fine. well @reddy got the answer just change .append to .html.

Answer (score 0):

> but the data retrieved was not remove or reload after the dropdown list changed.

You are appending the new response. You must just remove the existing html and add new. you can do that by using `$('#display').html()`. replace your code block with this one and it must work fine.

```
 $('#display').html(); // clean up the container
$.each(data, function(index, row){
              var fullname = row.fullname;      
              var number = row.number;           
          $('#display').append("<tr style=\"background-color:#ccc\"><td>id: </td><td> name: </td></tr><tr><td>"+number+"</td><td>"+fullname+"</td></tr>"); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! you saved ton of my time. :)

Comment: @Duke You can mark this as answer if its the right one.

Comment: oops! sorry to bother again. .html only display one last data looped, but .append was retrieving all the data.

Comment: So the only change to your original code was adding this `$('#display').html(); ` above your loop function. Thats all you had missed :)

Comment: I did put that above my loop. :(

Comment: Did you change the code inside your loop too, to make it append as before than using html??

Comment: ok,, revert back to what ever you had initially, then just add this line above the for loop. `$('#display').html();` I am sure you missed out something while altering the code

Comment: `$('#display').html();
              $.each(data, function(index, row){
                  var fullname = row.fullname;      
                  var number = row.number;  
                  var member = row.member;
                  var status = row.status;         
                  $('#display').append("<tr><td>id: </td><td> name: </td></tr><tr><td>"+number+"</td><td>"+fullname+"</td><td>"+member+"</td><td>"+status+"</td></tr>"); 
              });` here is my code block.

Answer (score 0):

Here how I get it to work by changing from $('#display').append to variable and put them into .innerHTML instead. Every time dropdown list change, it change the value and loop every values out correctly.

```
function fetch_select(val) {
    $.ajax({
       type: 'post',
       url: 'action.php?id=select-project',
       data: {
         get_option:val
       },
       dataType: 'json',  
       success: function(data)    {    

      // success: function (response) {
        //var data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

        var str = "<table id=\"cellcardtable\" class=\"table table-bordered table-condensed\"><tr><th width=\"15%\">#</th><th width=\"30%\">Full name</th><th width=\"30%\">Member since</th><th width=\"30%\">Status</th></tr>";
          $.each(data, function(index, row){

              var fullname = row.fullname;      
              var number = row.number;   
              var member = row.member;
              var status = row.status;        
              str = str + "<tr><td>"+number+"</td><td>"+fullname+"</td><td>"+member+"</td><td>"+status+"</td></tr>";

              document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=str;
          });
           str = str + "</table>" ; 
       }
    });
  }
```

Comment: I thought your `display` itself is a table. thats what your code in the question says. Anyways glad to know this worked for you. Happy coding :)

Comment: @Reddy well, thanks for your help. it wouldn't come to this without your help. Thanks!